# Pandas DataFrame: Merge rows with same id

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge, duplicates

I have a pandas `DataFrame` with the following property,

| timestamp | code | code_2 | q1 | q2 | q3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1525815633939 | 1 | 5 | 0.528285138670663 | 0.0 | -10.2012590087440983 |
| 1525815633979 | 1 | 5 | 0.728820351190643 | 0.0 | -10.1985732939503924 |
| 1525815633990 | 6 | 5 |  | 9.7439931640624877 | 10.25547685467354 |
| 1525815633990 | 6 | 5 | 0.92935559526222 |  |  |
| 1525815634000 | 6 | 5 |  | 9.7079931640624864 | 10.25475688648455 |
| 1525815634000 | 6 | 5 | 0.029623209410135 |  |  |

As you can see, sometimes an entry is split in two, although it is not double valued. The last two pairs of rows correspond to the same `timestamps`, same `code` and same `code_2` but `q1,q2,q3` are split.
(`timestamps`, `code` and `code_2` constitute my unique identifier).

What I want,

| timestamp | code | code_2 | q1 | q2 | q3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1525815633939 | 1 | 5 | 0.528285138670663 | 0.0 | -10.2012590087440983 |
| 1525815633979 | 1 | 5 | 0.728820351190643 | 0.0 | -10.1985732939503924 |
| 1525815633990 | 6 | 5 | 0.92935559526222 | 9.7439931640624877 | 10.25547685467354 |
| 1525815634000 | 6 | 5 | 0.029623209410135 | 9.7079931640624864 | 10.25475688648455 |

And I would also need to contemplate the following case, for which I would like to keep to discard the "complete row"

| timestamp | code | code_2 | q1 | q2 | q3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1525815633939 | 1 | 5 | 0.528285138670663 | 0.0 | -10.2012590087440983 |
| 1525815633979 | 1 | 5 | 0.728820351190643 | 0.0 | -10.1985732939503924 |
| 1525815633990 | 6 | 5 |  | 9.7439931640624877 | 10.25547685467354 |
| 1525815633990 | 6 | 5 | 0.92935559526222 |  |  |
| 1525815634000 | 6 | 5 | **0.984554565478545** | 9.7079931640624864 | 10.25475688648455 |
| 1525815634000 | 6 | 5 | 0.029623209410135 |  |  |

Comment: Well, I would create a function, which simply selects the first timestamp and go over all of the timesteps in order to find the equivalent timestamp then add the q1, q2, q3 together in both timestamp rows if there is NaN in one of them, else do nothing for the last case?

Comment: That is indeed an option, but I was expecting something more efficient. I have _loads_ of data and that would be very slow, don't you reckon?

Comment: And TBH, I was expecting this could be done with a built-in pandas method.

Comment: Well I would love that too :), there is definitly a built-in function where if two cells are having the same element they could be definitly summed up, or if one of them is NaN then replace it with the other value. But for your last case how would then the built-in function know which value to get? Like: `df.groupby('TimeStamp')['q1'].sum()` and for q2, q3 and so on

Comment: Try my solution for really better runtime (Also due to not using the apply function is relatively slow).      
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69055997/7836972

Comment: @Niv Dudovitch excellent, performance is also important. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for a way to do it **without the "apply" function, for better runtime** by using pandas build-in functions.

Compare runtimes with and without apply function:
dataset:

```
data_temp1 = {'timestamp':np.concatenate([np.arange(0,30000,1)]*2), 'code':[6,6, 5]*20000, 'code_2':[6,6, 5]*20000, 'q1':[0.134555,0.984554565478545, 54]*20000, 'q2':[9.7079931640624864,None, 43]*20000, 'q3':[10.25475688648455,None, 54]*20000} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data_temp1)
```

Solution by the use of apply similar to @Andrej Kesely example:

- **7.21 s** ± 8.56 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Solution without apply by my solution:

- **98.4 ms** ± 79.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

**My solution:**
(Will fill the empty cells only if exist. So, it's right according to both of your cases).

- Sort the rows by the number of empty cells
- Fill each row in each group by below row (Its ok because with sort them first)
- Remove rows with empty cells

```
columns_to_groupby = ["timestamp", "code"]
# Sort rows of a dataframe in descending order of None counts
df = df.iloc[df.isnull().sum(1).sort_values(ascending=True).index].set_index(columns_to_groupby)
# group by timestamp column, fill the None cells if exists, delete the incomplete rows (from which we filled in the others)
df.groupby(df.index).bfill().dropna()
```

**Examples:**

Example 1:

Input:
[image]

Result:
[image]

Example 2 (with row without empty cell):

Input:
[image]

Result:
[image]

As you can see, same result for both of them.

Comment: Just add the code_2 to the columns_to_groupby (I used it on mini example)

Answer (score 1):

For the question 1: you can `.groupby` by `"timestamp"`, `"code"`, `"code_2"` and then ffill()/bfill() the values, then drop duplicates:

```py
x = (
    df.groupby(["timestamp", "code", "code_2"])
    .apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
    .drop_duplicates(["timestamp", "code", "code_2"])
)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
       timestamp  code  code_2                 q1                  q2                    q3
0  1525815633939     1       5  0.528285138670663                 0.0  -10.2012590087440983
1  1525815633979     1       5  0.728820351190643                 0.0  -10.1985732939503924
2  1525815633990     6       5   0.92935559526222  9.7439931640624877     10.25547685467354
4  1525815634000     6       5  0.029623209410135  9.7079931640624864     10.25475688648455
```

---

For the question 2: You can `.sort_values` by how many `NaN`s there are in the row (so the full row will be at first place) and then do operation from the question 1:

```py
df["tmp"] = df[["q1", "q2", "q3"]].isna().sum(1)
df = df.sort_values(by="tmp").drop(columns="tmp")

x = (
    df.groupby(["timestamp", "code", "code_2"])
    .apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
    .drop_duplicates(["timestamp", "code", "code_2"])
)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
       timestamp  code  code_2                 q1                  q2                    q3
0  1525815633939     1       5  0.528285138670663                 0.0  -10.2012590087440983
1  1525815633979     1       5  0.728820351190643                 0.0  -10.1985732939503924
4  1525815634000     6       5  0.984554565478545  9.7079931640624864     10.25475688648455
2  1525815633990     6       5   0.92935559526222  9.7439931640624877     10.25547685467354
```

Comment: Excellent, this was what I was looking for. The _Pandas_ way to do it!